# Dolphindb cluster supports multiple data nodes using the same disk directory?

Tags: distributed-system, dolphindb

In my dolphindb cluster, there are 8 nodes, and the server has two disks. I plan to use one disk for every 4 nodes.

Can I configure it like this?

```
dfs_disk1_node%. volume=/mnt/disk1/volume
dfs_disk2_node%. volume=/mnt/disk2/volume
```

I'm just a little uncertain. Is it permissible for multiple nodes to use the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

No,it isn't.

volumns is the folder where data chunks are saved in the distributed file system on a data node. If 2 or more data nodes have the same directory setting, it will cause conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this way as long as these directory have no overlapping.